# fpdi merge pdf from stream not file

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, fpdf

I have a PHP script that uses tcpdf library to generate a PDF document that is then attached to an email and sent.
I need to repeat the document 4 times on a single A4 sheet, ie print 4 up on one sheet.
I can use the fpdi library to open an existing PDF document and place it several times in a new PDF using $pdf->setSourceFile('mypdf.pdf').
Is it possible to set the source from a binary stream rather than file?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I guess you already had that idea, but you can of course create your pdf file, save it to "temp.pdf", use the file and then delete it using `unlink('temp.pdf')`.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid that path. Thanks though. I can see where fget is used in the fpdi library but not sure if it can be extended.